# stack operations (main function)

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

So I implemented Stack basic operations in c++.I wrote the functions but I don't know how to implement the main the function such that to see the values from the stack.

header file

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_
#define HEADER_H_
#define DIM 15
typedef int Atom;

struct Element {
    Atom data;
    Element *link;
};

typedef Element* LinkedStack;

void initS(LinkedStack &S);
void push(LinkedStack &S, Atom a);
bool isEmpty2(LinkedStack &S);
void pop2(LinkedStack &S);
Atom top2(Stack &S);
#endif
```

The functions file

```
void initS(LinkedStack &S)
{
    S = nullptr;
}

void push(LinkedStack &S, Atom a)
{
    Element*nou = new Element;
    nou->data = a;
    nou->link = S;
    S = nou;
}

bool isEmpty2(LinkedStack &S)
{
    if (S == 0)
        return true;
    else return false;
}

void pop2(LinkedStack &S)
{
    LinkedStack aux = S;
    S = S->link;
    delete(aux);
}

Atom top2(LinkedStack &S)
{
    if (isEmpty2(S))
        return Atom();
    return S->data;
}
```

How I implemented the main function.I don't know how to see values, for example if I write cout<

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    LinkedStack S;
    initS(S);
    push(S, 2);
    push(S, 4);
    push(S, 6);
    push(S, 7);
    push(S, 10);
    return 0;

}

After I compile the program I don't see nothing in console.How to see the values from stack?
```

Comment: Based on the functions' names, which functions do you think you can use to examine the top of the stack, or pop off an element so you can look at the next element?

Comment: pop2, I solved the problem by changing this function.It returns an int now and it works.But I don't know how to write such that to be a void function

Comment: You should use `top2` to examine the *top* element without popping it, and `pop2` should only *pop* and return nothing. (And the "2"s in the names seem pointless.)

Comment: That is, you need to use both functions in order to print the entire stack.

Comment: Thank you!I solved it.